# Is it possible to add HTML when creating cards in AnkiWeb?

Tags: anki, software

I want to add my own HTML to Anki card. For example,

#### front side of the card

`<div class="word">word</div><div class="ipa">[IPA]</div><br>...`

Instead of the following (which I typed in return key after `word` when creating Anki card):

```
word
[IPA]
```

However, if I create such Anki cards from the web ([AnkiWeb](https://ankiuser.net/edit/)) by inserting the HTML, the actual card page just takes the input as text, not HTML. So the full HTML is just shown on the card.

I want to automate this process so I cannot use the app version.

Is it possible?

—-

#### EDIT

Hmmm... looking back and thinking about the implementation again, I feel it is much easier to handle SQLite database directly. Still, I’m looking forward to hearing an answer.

Comment: So you're looking for some sort of API to interact with AnkiWeb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you only want to automate something (I'm assuming with some sort of program or script), I would recommend taking a look at [AnkiConnect](https://foosoft.net/projects/anki-connect/), which provides a REST API for interacting with the local Anki database. Note that this does not directly interact with what is stored on AnkiWeb.

Comment: That's incredibly useful! I tried a few requests but it worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, it is even easier to write a Python script with AnkiConnect than dealing with Selenium and AnkiWeb.